# Regex - repeated data

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a data:

```
#object
id=91
name=precka
material=18ST2
#topology
2, 1, 5, 4, 9, 8, -1
#points
566.068643742472, 135, 9

#object
id=92
name=precka2
material=18ST2
#topology
6, 1, 6, 4, 9, 8, -1  
5, 1, 6, 4, 9, 8, -1
#points
216.068643742472, 235, 19 
216.068643742472, 235, 19
```

Now I need to get everything from id, name,material, #topology to #points. Currently I managed to write a regex that looks like this:

```
/#topology+([\s\S]*)#points([\s\S]+)/m
```

I want to change it to loop from #object to #object and take each #object data (id,name, topoloy..). Is this hard to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your text on `#object` and apply your regex to each element in the array returned by the function.

Comment: Its easy to split. No hard questions answered about using a regex to parse the data.

Comment: I felt like the question was more about how to parse each group than about extracting the data from a group. I might be wrong though...

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the contents of these three groups. But, if there are other groups, the regex needs some tweaking.

```
 # /^\#object(.*\n(?:^(?!\#object|\#topology|\#points)[^\n]*\n)*)^\#topology(.*\n(?:^(?!\#object|\#topology|\#points)[^\n]*\n)*)^\#points(.*\n(?:^(?!\#object|\#topology|\#points)[^\n]*\n)*)/m

 ^ \#object
 (                                  # (1 start), Object
      .* \n 
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?! \#object | \#topology | \#points )
           [^\n]* \n 
      )*
 )                                  # (1 end)
 ^ \#topology 
 (                                  # (2 start), Topology
      .* \n 
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?! \#object | \#topology | \#points )
           [^\n]* \n 
      )*
 )                                  # (2 end)
 ^ \#points
 (                                  # (3 start), Points
      .* \n 
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?! \#object | \#topology | \#points )
           [^\n]* \n 
      )*
 )                                  # (3 end)
```